# How to find formulas for spherical coordinates in terms of Cartesian coordinates using Maple?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, maple

We can go from spherical coordinates $(r, \theta, \phi)$ to cartesian coordinates $(x,y,z)$ using the equations:

$x=r sin(\theta) cos(\phi)$

$y = r sin(\theta) sin(\phi)$

$z = r cos(\theta)$

Consider the task of finding formulas for $r$, $\theta$, and $\phi$ in terms of $x,y$, and $z$. The three equations above are a system that can be solved for $r$, $\theta$, and $\phi$.

This is a relatively easy task with pen and paper.

$r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$

$\theta = cos^{-1}\frac{z}{r}=cos^{-1}\frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}$

$\phi = tan^{-1} \frac{y}{x}$

How can we get Maple to obtain the same result?

If we try:

```
solve({r*sin(t)*cos(p) = x, r*sin(t)*sin(p) = y, r*cos(t) = z}, [r, t, p])
```

We obtain some very long and relatively illegible expression.

[image]

If my reasoning is correct about the simplicity of solving the original problem, why is it apparently not as straightforward in Maple? Furthermore, is there a way in Maple to obtain a relatively nice-looking solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
simplify(solve({r*sin(t)*cos(p) = x,
                r*sin(t)*sin(p) = y,
                r*cos(t) = z},
               [r, t, p], explicit)[1]) assuming real:

   [r = (x^2+y^2+z^2)^(1/2),
    t = arctan((x^2+y^2)^(1/2),z),
    p = arctan(y,x)]
```